# ssh still asking for password

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have two servers called: "eps" and "dev".  On server dev I have added the public key of eps to the authorized_keys file.  I have then restarted SSH service on the dev server to ensure it picks up the new public key I added to the authorized_keys file.

However when I then try and ssh into "dev" from "eps", I'm prompted for passphrase for a key.  the exact prompt is: Enter passphrase for key '/home/webmaster/.ssh/id_rsa':

Why is this happening?  I thought it should just log me into the dev server right away.

Comment: Did you do a: ssh-copy-id <USERNAME>@<REMOTEHOST>

Comment: No, I manually copied and pasted it.  Let me give that a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating the SSH key using ssh-keygen you are prompted for a password to secure the private key. Therefore for SSH to use the key the password has to be entered to unlock the private key locally, which is why you are seeing the "Enter passphrase for key". This is not the same as the password to authenticate the user on the SSH server.

In order to have a password-less login you need to create a keyfile with ssh-keygen which has an empty password.

Comment: Thanks.  That turned out to be the issue.  I actually didn't know that I needed to enter the passphrase for server eps if I wanted to log into dev.  Strange initially but I can see why that is the case now. :-)

Comment: You might also need to remove the contents of the .ssh directories of both the "from" and "to" hosts to start with a clean slate before actioning the above.